# Override intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm creating notification using following code (Kotlin)

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
           ........
      .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 891, ctx.newIntent<MainActivity>()
            .putExtra("id", member.id)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0))
```

So when notification is tapped `MainActivity` will select user, from which notification arrived.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    val id = intent?.getStringExtra("id") ?: return
    selectUser(extra)
}
```

I'm sending 2 notifications from 2 different users. After click on first notification it works correct (id==_User1UUID) and selects user. Then I press back, send another notification from second user, tap on it and intent still contains previous user id and selects it (checked through breakpoint).

I know, it's because `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, but I must keep only one instance of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Put 'android:launchMode="singleTask"' attribute
in activity in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: For more info -- [link] https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: @keyur9779 I already have this in manifest, but isn't this flag required too?

Comment: @keyur9779 tried to remove `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, still only one instance created and works correctly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are probably having is that you aren't generating unique `PendingIntent`s. If you had 2 Notifications for different users, they would both be using the same `PendingIntent` and you would therefore see the same `id` extra in both.

To create unique `PendingIntent`s, change this:

```
 .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 891, ctx.newIntent<MainActivity>()
        .putExtra("id", member.id)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0))
```

to this:

```
int randomNumber = ... // Use some random number here, or use your "id" if your "id" can be converted to an integer here.
                       //  This random number needs to be unique for each Notification you create.

 .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, randomNumber, ctx.newIntent<MainActivity>()
        .putExtra("id", member.id)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), u))
```

Answer (score 1):

you actually need the given code to make each notification unique

```
notificationManager.notify( (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE) /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

if you already did this then try the code given below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: I just removed `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` it works, but thanks for trying to help